# new subdomain setup to apache vhost ServerName. Why I see many requests from unkown sources?

Tags: apache2

I got a new vserver and configured a new subdomain to that IP.

I run there a private django site behind apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mysub.mytld.de
```

Now I see in other_vhosts_access.log many requests to my domain with paths for other websites, ie. wordpress and much more.

I wonder how is that possible?

Well, to tell you my aim, it is to see in django-request app who of my users access my site's resources and it should not be cluttered with other requests.

Comment: The bots have found an IP address with a webserver.  They are trying to brute force their way in, using whatever domain name (if any) and url they can come up with.  Don't bother logging them, disable logging for "other" vhosts.

Comment: Is this the first virtualhost? If so, its being used as a catch all. Go spammers!